# How do I display a memo field to a Form in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have looked at the previous questions asked relating to this but haven't been able to find a solution. I have a table with a memo field called "Comments", and I am trying to display all the history of the field in the form. In the text box properties in the control source I have this:

ColumnHistory([Positions], [Comments], [JobID=]&[JobID]) (Positions is the table name, Comments is the memo field, and JobID is the primary key indentifier). I get a #Name error in the field and I dont understand why. I am very inexperienced with databases but am trying to learn and do this project. Any Help is appreciated Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure the Comments field's AppendOnly property is set to **True** or this will not work.

Next, the code in the text box control should read:

```
= Application.ColumnHistory("Positions", "Comments", "JobID=" & Me.JobID & "")
```

If any of your variables, objects or controls is different than stated, you might need to tweak that a bit.

I see you're new here, so please make sure that you confirm whether or not this worked for you so future visitors with similar questions will know if the answer is viable.

Comment: Thank you for the help, It is giving me a #Name error now. When I was trying to do this in a query, I was having the same issue as it was asking for a parameter when I put the Table name correctly. I think the issue is coming from the Table name but I have no idea why or what is wrong with it. It is spelled the same everywhere. Thank you for the help again it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got it to work. I opened a much older version of the database saved under a different name and then everything seemed to work. I don't really understand why but it's working now haha. Thank you for the help again. I hope this is where I am supposed to put my confirmation.

Comment: Usually you either click the up arrow or the checkmark (or both), which gives me points for offering a solution that works and also makes it easier for any future visitors to notice that the answer was helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the answer but i can't click the arrow because I do not have enough rep. Thank you though